# How to get the solicitors who wrote the will to respond to a Larke v Nugus request?

Tags: england-and-wales, probate

Is there a valid reason to withhold a [Larke v Nugus](https://www.thegazette.co.uk/all-notices/content/101713)  request when there is no personal representative?  Imagine the situation where a person in England dies testate and:

- All executors have renounced their positions.
- Residual beneficiaries are a number of separate charities.
- None of the residual beneficiaries have agreed to act as the
  deceased's personal representative.
- The solicitors who wrote the will refuse to respond to a Larke v
  Nugus request from the deceased's family (next-of-kin) on the basis
  of there being no personal representative.

How can the next-of-kin get the solicitors who wrote the will to respond to the Larke v Nugus request?  Could a Legacy beneficiary act as the deceased's personal representative.

Comment: See also https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/77185/how-to-request-a-larke-v-nugus-with-no-executors-or-personal-representative

Answer (score 2):

**How can the next-of-kin get the solicitors who wrote the will to respond..?**

By the most appropriate person applying to be the Personal Representative and then making the request.

> ... if the people appointed as executors are unwilling or unable to act, the estate will instead be sorted out by an administrator. The administrator will usually be a close relative of the person who has died, if there is one. In order to be an administrator, the person must apply for a Grant of **Letters of Administration from the court** which grants the power to unfreeze the assets and administer the estate. [Source](https://www.bereavementadvice.org/topics/personal-representatives/)

Comment: Rick: When you say "applying to be the Personal Representative" are you referring to applying for Letters of Administration or something different?

Comment: @NickC Letters of Administration which are granted by the Probate Court

Comment: Next of Kin cannot apply for Letters of Administration as they are not one of the Residual Beneficiaries.

Comment: @NickC That's news to me. What has led you to that conclusion?

Comment: I was under the impression that only those who are beneficiaries could apply for Letters of Administration, is that incorrect?  Can a non-beneficiary apply for Letters of Administration.